Available Hydroponic data set
I have started studying on a mathematical modeling platform aiming for providing a solution for farmers in specifically Hydroponic industry. This model would entirely enable farmers to realzie which portfolio is cost beneficial when it comes to planning for their cultivation on multiple avlaible farms either land or vertical ones (No matter which farm is subject to consideration).For this purpose I need any data regarding the:
Amount of energy (kw/h) required to grow/sow a unit of product
Amount of water and its associated cost for sow/growing on unit of every products
the area of land which every produce would be occupied on farming.
labor in FTE or hour required for both harvesting or sowing produce on farms
I am also open for any data might be useful to benefit the model with more accuracy level.
Let me know if you farmers or industry owners have such data
